# No encuentro como retornar los datos desde el hijo en firebase

Tags: json, array, firebase, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo la siguiente insercion de datos a firebase por medio de realtime Database que implemente desde Android Studio con Java:

```
FirebaseDatabase dBa = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = dBa.getReference("DataLegalizaciones/");
String keyId = myRef.push().getKey();
myRef.child(extraName).child(keyId).updateChildren(infor);
```

y los datos se ven asi en mi bd:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-- extraName corresponde al nombre del usuario que se encuentre logueado.

-- keyId es la llave unica que genera realtime Database en este caso **LnOkyI_ICkYGjd5e5Xk**

-- infor corresponde al HashMap que he creado para almacenar los datos que se anidan dentro de **LnOkyI_ICkYGjd5e5Xk**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy recuperando estos datos por medio de **Google Apps Scripts** para que cada uno de los campos que contiene cada una de las llaves en una hoja de calculo se ubiquen según corresponda la información...

Funciona si agrego manualmente a mi script la coleccion "Andres Mora" en esta parte de mi script:

```
function getDataFromRealtime() {


var firebaseUrl = "https://my-roodent.firebaseio.com/DataLegalizaciones/Andres Mora/";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
  var data = base.getData();
  for(var i in data) {
    //Logger.log(data[i].firstName + ' ' + data[i].lastName);
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.appendRow([data[i].nombreUsuario, data[i].ccnit,data[i].conceptoGasto,
                     data[i].descripcionGasto,data[i].fechaGasto,data[i].impuestoGasto,
                     data[i].ivaGasto,data[i].lugarGasto,
                     data[i].proveedorGasto,data[i].razonSocial,
                     data[i].retencionGasto,data[i].subtotalGasto,
                     data[i].totalGasto,data[i].urlImagenGasto]);
  }
}
```

y puedo ver la información así en mi Google Sheet:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema surge cuando intento recuperar la informacion en esta linea `var firebaseUrl = "https://my-roodent.firebaseio.com/DataLegalizaciones/Andres Mora/";` de todos los usuarios registrados y no solo de Andres Mora y que no se repitan los datos...

Comment: Una sugerencia, no uses espacios en blanco para el nombre de las referencias, usa un _ para unirlos, por ejemplo Andres_Mora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema en tu código es que en la referencia

```
var firebaseUrl = "https://my-roodent.firebaseio.com/DataLegalizaciones/Andres Mora/"
```

Solamente vas a conseguir toda la informacion de Andres Mora pero no de todos los usuarios.

Cuando haces el siguiente for

```
for(var i in data) {
...
}
```

Lo haces dentro de la referencia de Andres Mora

Si queres obtener de todos los usuarios deberias mover la referencia a

```
var firebaseUrl = "https://my-roodent.firebaseio.com/DataLegalizaciones/
```

Entonces el for va a recorrer por todos los usuarios

usa `data[i].key` para obtener la key de cada usuario cuando buscas sus datos

Comment: Muchas gracias cambie como comentaste la linea de código pero ademas estructure un poco mejor los nodos de mi base de datos y me ayudo a acceder mas fácil también.

Comment: De nada, cualquier otra consulta estamos para ayudar